# Get type of items in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, reflection, mvvm, collections

I have a view (consists of a listview) that is binded to some observable collection. In other words I have:

```
var someCollection = new ObservableCollection<ClassFoo>();
// initialize someCollection

ListView someView = new ListView();
someView.DataContext = someCollection;
someView.ItemsSource = someCollection;
```

Note:

- `someView` is located on **Project1.dll** and `someCollection` on **Project2.dll**
- **Project2.dll** has a reference to **Project1.dll** AND **Project1.dll** DOES NOT have a reference to **Project2.dll**

Therefore on my view I have a reference to someCollection of type `ObservableCollection<object>` because I will get a compilation error if it where to be of its actual type `ObservableCollection<ClassFoo>` because I would have to add a reference to Project2.dll.

For some reason I cannot add that reference and I my boss wants me to create commands etc...

---

The last part just explains why I want to do this but in short I am looking for:

```
  ObservableCollection<object> myUnknownObservableCollection = someReference;
  // I know that someReferce is of type ObservableCollection<ClassFoo>
  var x = myUnknownObservableCollection.GetType().GetTypeOfItems.....
```

at the end I will like x to be equal to `typeof(ClassFoo)` how can I do that with reflection given that someReference is of type `ObservableCollection<ClassFoo>`?

---

### Edit

I got a solution!! Here it is:

```
    class Person 
    {
        public string Name { get { return "Antonio"; } }
    }

    .. 

    // view code:

    IEnumerable<object> uncknownObject;

    // view model does this:
    uncknownObject = new ObservableCollection<Person>( );

    // continuation of view code:

    var observCol = uncknownObject.GetType( );

    var x = ( ( dynamic )observCol ).GenericTypeArguments[ 0 ]; 

    var instance = ( Person )Activator.CreateInstance( x );

    Console.WriteLine( instance.Name ); // Print Antonio!!!
```

It will be nice to be able to do it without the dynamic data type though

---

### Edit 2

[**Here is a solution running .net 4.0 without using the dynamic type**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639987/why-reflection-does-not-find-property)

Comment: Can Project1 make an interface for the class?

Comment: I think @SLaks's idea is the best solution. Create an interface in Project1 and have `ClassFoo` implement it (since Project2 *does* reference Project1). Then you can use that interface instead of `object` and you're done.

Comment: I wish lol. I am just being lazy. I can implement a command that will take care of that. I ask this question primarily to learn. I just need to create a new item of type `ClassFoo` with no parameters and it makes no sense having to create a command then bind it just to do a simple operation... If what am asking is to hard then I will stop being lazy lol

Comment: @SLaks approach is the best solution, you also can use reflection to load dll dynamically to avoid circular dll reference

Comment: @CuongLe: Loading DLLs dynamically will not help at all.

Comment: No interface needed hehe... Got it working :)  

PS: The interface part is prob the best approach. Thanks for that suggestion. I will prob do that

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, and mark it as the best answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use mvvm, then dynamic type will not help in binding.
You might have to use an interface as SLaks suggested

```
public interface IClassFoo
{
   string Name { get; }
}

public class ClassFoo : IClassFoo
{
    public string Name { get { return "Antonio"; } }
}

//Usage 
var someCollection = new ObservableCollection<IClassFoo>();
```