# Why reflection does not find property

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I have the class:

```
    class Person 
    {
        public string Name { get { return "Antonio"; } }
    }
```

and the Code:

```
        IEnumerable<object> uncknownObject;

        uncknownObject = new ObservableCollection<Person>( );

        var observCol = uncknownObject.GetType( );

        var x = ( ( dynamic )observCol ).GenericTypeArguments[ 0 ];

        var y = observCol.GetProperty( "GenericTypeArguments" );

        var instance = ( Person )Activator.CreateInstance( x );

        Console.WriteLine( instance.Name ); // Print Antonio!!!
```

why does `y == null` ?

Note the picture:

[image]

the debugger shows that the property **GenericTypeArguments** should exist and the code shows the opossite. It can be proven that the debugger is right and that property exist because then how come x is not null.  If that property exists then why `y` is equal to null!!!???

---

### Edit

Thanks to Ani I now have:

```
        IEnumerable<object> uncknownObject;

        uncknownObject = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        var observCol = uncknownObject.GetType();

        var genTypeArgsProperty = typeof(Type).GetProperty("UnderlyingSystemType");

        var genTypeArgsValue = (genTypeArgsProperty.GetValue(observCol, null));

        var f = genTypeArgsValue.GetType().GetMethod("GetGenericArguments");

        IEnumerable<object> result = (IEnumerable<object>)f.Invoke(genTypeArgsValue, null);

        var x = result.FirstOrDefault();

        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(  (Type)x );
```

**[In case of curios why I needed that functionality click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639368/get-type-of-items-in-observablecollection)**

Comment: Is that VS 2010? `GenericTypeArguments` did not exist until .Net 4.5.

Comment: @mikez: So how does it show up in the debugger???

Comment: @leppie I have no idea but according to the docs, it was added in .NET 4.5 (Supported frameworks is only .NET 4.5): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.generictypearguments.aspx

Comment: @mikez: I can only assume, it still uses .NET 4.5 if installed, even when using VS2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish with all this meta-meta-reflection, but you seem to have misunderstood what `Type.GetProperty` does. It gets meta-data for a property on the *actual* type represented by the `System.Type` instance (in this case, `ObservableCollection<Person>`). It does *not* get meta-data for a property declared on `System.Type` itself, unless of course you call it on a `System.Type` representing `System.Type` itself.

In your case, `y` is null since `ObservableCollection<Person>` does not have a property named "GenericTypeArguments".

Try this instead:

```
var genTypeArgsProperty = typeof(Type).GetProperty("GenericTypeArguments");

var genTypeArgsValue = (Type[]) (genTypeArgsProperty.GetValue(observCol, null));

var onlyTypeArgValue = genTypeArgsValue.Single();
```

Comment: `var observCol = uncknownObject.GetType( );` So yes, it is a type, no?

Comment: But this type needs to represent `System.Type` for the OP's purposes. This is all very meta. :)

Comment: wow I was about to try it and on this computer I don't even get the GenericTypeArguments property. In other words now my program crashes whereas on the other computer it ran fine. That is wierd. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's possibly because the GenericTypeArguments property is new to .NET 4.5. In previous versions, you'd have to use the GetGenericArguments method.

Comment: Ani thanks so much! one last question... so what are all the properties that I see on the debugger? How can I tell weather those properties are from the actual type or not? I still have trouble understanding where the property GenericTypeArguments comes from.

Comment: Ohh never mind I understand now. I thought that `observCol` was of type `ObservableCollection<Person>` and it is not.

Comment: The GenericTypeArguments is a property on System.Type. For a specific System.Type *instance*, its *value* will represent the type-arguments of the type represented by the containing System.Type instance. Not clear?

Comment: very clear thanks so much. The code does not work though... It makes no sense. I am posting an edit now...

Comment: I suggest posting a new question.

Comment: you are right the problem is because I am not runing .net 4.5 . Once I try it on 4.5 I am sure it is going to work. Thanks for the explination it was very clear.

Answer (score 3):

This code works with net framework 4:

```
        IEnumerable<object> uncknownObject;

        uncknownObject = new ObservableCollection<Person>();



        var observCol = uncknownObject.GetType();

        var x = ((dynamic) observCol).UnderlyingSystemType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        var y = observCol.GetGenericArguments();

        var instance = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance(x);

        Console.WriteLine(instance.Name); // Print Antonio!!!
```

Comment: fix getting y. observCol.GetMethod("GetGenericArguments", Type.EmptyTypes) returns null. so may be is extension method

Comment: +1 thanks to your answer I could make Ani's anwer work now that I switch to a .net 4.0 computer.